# Retrieved date, time off by 7 hours?

Tags: php, drupal, date, datetime

I am having trouble displaying the correct date, well actually its only the time.

In the db the date is stored in this form: '2012-09-28 23:30:00' (off by 7 hours of actual date time)

That is the value for a date of an event.

When I retrieve it using this script(for drupal): 
`$ttdate = $obj->field_date_test_value; 
    $nttdate = strtotime($ttdate); 
    $okdate = format_date($nttdate, $type = 'medium'); 
    print $okdate;`

...it works fine but the time is off by 7 hours. So instead of showing 'Fri, 9/28/2012 - 4:30pm' it shows 'Fri, 9/28/2012 - 11:30pm'.

Note that on the event's page, drupal retrieves the correct time...

I did some research and I figured it has to do with the timezone? But I have the timezone set to Los Angeles so I am not quite sure what is going on. Maybe its my script?

Comment: Where are you located? Where is your server located?

Comment: @Paul Im located in central cali, not sure where the server is located. I think the greengeeks website says their data centers are located in Chicago, IL.

Comment: Sounds like the database is configured to use GMT, but you're in PDT. They're 7 hours apart.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you use the Date module.

This is probably because the Date module saves the date in UTC and alters the output on rendering (using [format_date()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/format_date/7), I think). Since you do not format the date in your own code, you see the raw UTC time (which is PDT + 7 hours) even though the correct date is displayed by the event page.

[The bottom of this page](http://drupal.org/node/767182) explains how timezones are handled in the Date module. My guess is that either the first or third scenario is relevant in your case.

Comment: I did format the date using format_date() in my own code. I think I also tried format_date($nttdate, $type = 'medium', $timezone = 'America/Los_angeles'); didnt have much luck either.

Comment: Try this instead: format_date($nttdate, $type = 'medium', $format = '', $timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles'). This works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following in mysql:

```
set time_zone = '-07:00';
```

Comment: where do I put this? In the query?

Comment: This only works if the field is a `TIMESTAMP` field. It has no effect on `DATETIME` or `CHAR` fields.

Comment: You should send this as a query on the same connection, before sending the SELECT query.