# PHP date() returns incorrect time (off one hour)

Tags: php, date, timezone

PHP 5.2.17. The time on server is 9:40 and the timezone is Europe/Moscow:

```
Tue Nov 12 09:40:59 MSK 2013
```

- The timezone in php.ini is set to: date.timezone Europe/Moscow
- The timezone set by date_default_timezone_set() is Europe/Moscow

But the date() function returns time one hour off:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get() . date(" Y-m-d G:i:s")
```

output:

```
Europe/Moscow 2013-11-12 8:40:59
```

How do I fix that? I've tried installing the latest /usr/share/zoneinfo with the same result

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072744/php-date-one-hour-ahead-of-server-time-dst-problem?rq=1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433529/retrieved-date-time-off-by-7-hours#answer-12436717)

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer by the first link

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bhavik Shah, I found the answer:

```
pecl install timezonedb
```

Then added "extension=timezonedb.so" to php.ini